# Trigger after delete doesn't work after change

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I wrote a trigger in T-SQL using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and after I noticed a flaw, I narrowed down my trigger. This made one of my triggers cease to work and I can't figure out why.

The workflow is supposed to be this: Delete Event, through a foreign key on EventId, EventEquipment is deleted. Since the equipment is no longer needed, the NumberofEquipmentNeeded should be added back to the availability of the equipment in a table called EquipmentAvailabilities.

Below is my code. I have the reduce availability on insert working and had this add availability after delete work until I added in to only do it for that date

```
create trigger trgAddNumberAvailable
on EventEquipments
after delete
as
begin

    declare @eventEquipmentId int;

    select @eventEquipmentId = EventEquipmentId
    from deleted;

    declare @eventId int;

    select @eventId = EventId
    from deleted;

    --selects the eventID from EventEquipment

    declare @eventDate date;

    select @eventDate = EventDate
    from Events 
    where Events.EventId = @eventId;
   --finds the date for the Event that was chosen above becuase EventEquipment does not contain date

    declare @equipmentId int;

    select @equipmentId = EquipmentId
    from deleted
    where deleted.EventEquipmentId = @eventEquipmentId;

    declare @numberRequested int;

    select @numberRequested = NumberOfEquipmentNeeded
    from deleted 
    where deleted.EventEquipmentId = @eventEquipmentId;

    update EquipmentAvailabilities
    set NumberAvailable = NumberAvailable + @numberRequested
    where EquipmentId = @equipmentId  
      and EquipmentAvailabilityDate = @eventDate;

    --will update the availability for the equipment from insert and the date it is
    --available that was chosen from the Event date from the event that was deleted
```

Comment: Your trigger has a **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is not the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `DELETE` statement affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then the `Deleted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `select @eventEquipmentId = EventEquipmentId from deleted;` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: the delete statement affects only one row at a time

Comment: It may be deleting one row,but you should be prepared for bulk delete.
Also  new developer are not aware of all these thing so you should be extra precautious in important biz rule.Also when you hv so many id then what is the need for eventdate ?Something do not seem rgihts among table relation.you can copy paste your trigger script in SSMS and instead of deleted put real table name.this way you can debug it.

Answer (score 0):

you hv use so many times Select .. from deleted just to populate variable.
Instead use one Select and populate all variables.

Also notice the alternative query.Relation between tables are not clear.

```
create trigger trgAddNumberAvailable
on EventEquipments
after delete
as
begin

    declare @eventEquipmentId int;
    declare @eventId int; 
    declare @eventDate date;
    declare @equipmentId int;
    declare @numberRequested int;

    select @eventEquipmentId = EventEquipmentId, @eventId = EventId
    ,@equipmentId = EquipmentId,@numberRequested = NumberOfEquipmentNeeded
    from deleted;

     --selects the eventID from EventEquipment
      select @eventDate = EventDate
    from Events 
    where Events.EventId = @eventId;
   --finds the date for the Event that was chosen above becuase EventEquipment does not contain date

    update EquipmentAvailabilities
    set NumberAvailable = NumberAvailable + @numberRequested
    where EquipmentId = @equipmentId  
      and EquipmentAvailabilityDate = @eventDate;

    --will update the availability for the equipment from insert and the date it is
    --available that was chosen from the Event date from the event that was deleted

    --OR (alternative query for bulk delete ,(Correct the join))
    update EquipmentAvailabilities
    set NumberAvailable = NumberAvailable + @numberRequested
    from EquipmentAvailabilities EA
    inner join   deleted d
    on ea.EquipmentId = d.equipmentId  
    inner join Events E 
    on d.EventId=e.EventId
    where 
      ea.EquipmentAvailabilityDate = e.eventDate;
```